Azure DataBricks Cluster usage metrics
Is there any way that I can log Azure databricks cluster usage metrics like CPU, Memory, Network, Throughput usage and etc.... ?
There are ways before 13.3 series, is there any way post 13.3 series (Excluding DataDog & Grafana)

As it is said here https://community.databricks.com/t5/get-started-discussions/is-it-possible-to-view-databricks-cluster-metrics-using-rest-api/td-p/57202 It seems to not be possible right now. But the discussion is from january so...

You can find some of these metrics in the System Tables and more specifically in the node_timeline table.
SELECT *
FROM system.compute.node_timeline
WHERE workspace_id = "<your_workspace_id"
AND cluster_id = "<your_cluster_id>"


It is also available visually in the Metrics Tab of your cluster.
https://<workspace_url>/compute/clusters/<cluster_id>/metrics 



Hi @Axel Thanks for your response, let me try this out and let you know here.
